# Is there an interactive chat/service for Stack Exchange sites, like Discord?

Tags: support, chat

Is there a place for just informal discussion for particular Stack Exchange communities?

Maybe audio and video chats or making friends?

Answer (score 7):

There are three distinct chat servers attached to Stack Exchange sites: https://chat.stackexchange.com for the entire network, https://chat.stackoverflow.com for Stack Overflow, and https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com for Meta Stack Exchange. To chat on each server, you will need at least 20 reputation on the parent site.

There is at least one main chatroom for every site except for Stack Overflow, with varying degrees of activity. For instance, the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) is the main chatroom for Meta Stack Exchange.

You can use text and images while chatting, but not audio or video. Unread chat notifications will appear in your site inbox.

For some more information on how chat works, see the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/FAQ). It's a bit outdated but still good enough to give you a general idea of how chat works.

---

In addition to the official chat system, many sites also have unofficial chatrooms hosted elsewhere, such as Discord, Slack, Matrix, and IRC.